# Fetch puppet scripts on client side

Tags: puppet

I do not have access to puppet server.
But i can log on ssh ok target servers (clients).

Is there a way to log puppet scripts on target server?
I want to know which operation have been done on each target server.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can run `puppet agent --verbose` to log all actions.

Comment: Yes but if actions have been made before ? Does client computer store scripts somewhere ?

Comment: @Bob5421 AFAIK, client doesn't store scripts locally. If you agent already has logged enabled you can check system logs.

Comment: Okay what will happen if a launch a second agent with log option while work has already been done by first agent ?